# An Issue with problem Definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

**Consider the following definition**

> Suppose $B\subseteq\mathbf{Z^+}$ and $B$ is infinite. We now define a
>   function $f :\mathbf{Z^+}\to B$ by recursion as follows: For all
>   $n\in\mathbf{Z^+}$, $f (n) = the\ smallest\ element\ of\ B \backslash\{ f (m) |m \in \mathbf{Z^+},m < n\}$ .
>
> Of course, the definition is recursive because the specification of
>   $f(n)$ refers to $f (m)$ for all $m < n$.

*Does the above definition make sense if so could you explain how am i to determine $f(n)$ given any n ?*

Comment: Note that $\{ f (m) \mid m \in \mathbf{Z^+},m < 1\} = \emptyset\,$, so $f (1) = \min B \setminus\{ f (m) \mid m \in \mathbf{Z^+},m < 1\}$ $= \min B \setminus \emptyset$ $= \min B$, and the rest is standard recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure does make sense.

We may write $B=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$ with $a_1<a_2<a_3<\ldots$, so $f(1)=\left(\text{the smallest element of } B \right)=a_1$.

Now $f(2)=\left(\text{the smallest element of } B \backslash\{ f (1)\}=\{a_2,a_3,\ldots\}\right)=a_2$.

Then $f(3)=\left(\text{the smallest element of } B \backslash\{ f (1),f(2)\}=\{a_3,\ldots\}\right)=a_3$, etc.

So we see that $f(n)=a_n$ for any $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Might (or might not) be worth pointing out that a) we *can* write $B = \{a_1, a_2,a_3....\}$ with $a_1< a_2< a_3...$ for three reasons i) $B\subset Z$ means $B$ is countable and ii) $B \subset Z^{+}$ means every subset has a first element and because it is countable iii) every element has an imediate successor (i.e. the first element of all the elements larger than the element).  And that b) as B is infinite $B \setminus \{f(m)|m < n\}$ will never be empty.  .... Or maybe it's *not* worth pointing those out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also state the recursion as below:

- $f(0)=\min B$
- $f(n+1)=\min\{b\in B\mid b>f(n)\}$

I feel it is easier to grasp at first lecture.

You could even cheat the initialisation step by defining $f(0)=-1$ for instance and consider only $f(1)$ and its successors as worthy of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Let's *think*.

What is $f(1)$?  $f(1)$ is the smallest element of $B\setminus \{f(m)|m < 1; m \in \mathbb Z^+\} = B\setminus  \{f(m)|m< 1; m\ge 1\}=B\setminus \emptyset = B$.

So $f(1) = $ smallest element of $B$.  As $B \subset \mathbb Z^+$ then by the well-ordered principal $B$ *does* have a smallest element so that is well defined.

What is $f(2)?$  $f(2)$ is the smallest element of $B\setminus \{f(m)|m < 2; m\in\mathbb Z^=\} = B\setminus\{f(1)\}$.  As $B$ is infinite $B \setminus \{f(1)\}$ is not empty and as it is a subset of $\mathbb Z^+$ then $B\setminus \{f(1)\}$ has a least element.

And we can continue this forever.  $K_n = \{f(m)|m < n\}$ will always be finite and well defined if $f(m)|m < n$ is well-defined.  As $B$ is infinite $B \setminus K_n$ will never be empty.  And as $B\setminus K_n \subset \mathbb Z^+$ it will always have a least element so $f(n)$ will be well defined so long as $f(m)|m < n$ are.  And by strong induction they will be, as $f(1)$ is.

So this is well defined.

Another way to put this:

$B \subset Z^{+}$ and so $B$ is countable we can index $B= \{b_1, b_2, b_3,.....\}$.  $B$ is infinite.  $B \subset \mathbb Z^{+}$ and by the well ordering principle we can order $\{b_1,b_2,.....\}$ as $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,....\}$ where $c_1 < c_2 < c_3 < ....$.

Than $f(n) = c_n$.

That's all it is.